# How get user name in MVC WebAPI Controller

Tags: asp.net, basic-authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a Logon Controller Get method where I want to return the user id.
I am using basic authorization and all work fine but in the Get method I am not able to get the correct user id.

This is the code :

```
public class LogonController : ApiController
{
    [BasicAuthorize] 
    public string Get()
    {
        int id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; // returns -1
        return id.ToString();
    }
}
```

My application is based on MVC 4 internet template with authentication mode="Forms"
I am not sure how to configure the two authentication modes even they seem to be working.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume since you're in the `LogonController` doing a get, that user isn't logged in at that point. Isn't that the reason that `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` returns -1?

Comment: Maybe you should set it when you check authorization in BasicAuthorizeAttribute?

Comment: @Steven True, since the OnAuthorization override of BasicAuthenticationAttribute calls WebSecurity.Login() succesfully, and access to get is enabled, I don't know what is missing.

Comment: Maybe somewhat make another request that set CurrentUserId to default?
Try to hard code by setting id in BasicAuthorize.

Comment: @Roman I don't think I could have another request, I am debugging the application on my laptop. 
I have also noticed that in the default MVC AccountController, user information is not there immediately after calling WebSecurity.Login.
In the spy window, I see User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false